# Double values for Longitude and Latitude not passing to googlemap Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a dataobject that contains longs latitude and longitude. I am passing these from a method in a fragment, that calls the parent activity method to show a googlemap.

The problem is, the longitude and latitude keep resulting as (0,0). I have checked that the object is setting and getting the correct figures.

The figures are correct in the fragment and in the call to showmap, but the marker keeps showing as the default 0,0.

I have the map in my activity xml, within a framelayout, that I change the visibility. (I think this is the problem, it's a blank map)

I have spent hours on this, and have now come here, cap in hand.

This is the relevant parts of the code:

My fragment code:

```
/**
 * Get latitude and longitude from dataobject and pass into
 * showMap method of activity.
 */
public void showMap() {
     double lat = dataObject.getLatitude();
     double long_ = dataObject.getLongitude();
     String name = dataObject.getName();

    ((MyActivity) getActivity()).showMap(lat, long_, name);
}
```

My activity code:

```
public void showMap(double lat, double _long, String _title) {
    GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, _long)).title(_title));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5f));
}
```

My activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
style="@style/RLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my">

 ....

<FrameLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

I figure I'm missing something essential, but I can't figure out what it is.

Adding logs:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
//Log.
Log.d("1. act lat="+String.valueOf(lat),"act long="+String
                .valueOf(_long) );
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//Log.
Log.d("2. act lat=" + String.valueOf(lat),
                "act long=" + String.valueOf(_long));
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, _long)).title(_title));
//Log.
Log.d("3. act lat="+String.valueOf(lat),"act long="+String
                .valueOf(_long) );
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5f));
//Log.
Log.d("4. act lat="+String.valueOf(lat),"act long="+String
                .valueOf(_long) );
FrameLayout frameLayout =
                (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.third);
Log.d("5. act lat="+String.valueOf(lat),"act " +
                "long="+String
                .valueOf(_long) );
frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Log.d("6. act lat=" + String.valueOf(lat),
                "act long=" + String.valueOf(_long));
```

> 07-09 05:57:37.147  32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/1. act
>   lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3 07-09 05:57:37.157 
>   32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/2. act lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3
>   07-09 05:57:37.167  32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/3. act
>   lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3 07-09 05:57:37.167 
>   32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/4. act lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3
>   07-09 05:57:37.167  32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/5. act
>   lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3 07-09 05:57:37.167 
>   32317-32317/thiscode.databasedemo D/6. act lat=-42.9﹕ act long=147.3

Comment: Have you logged the values? Maybe right before calling showMap, check your lat and long_

Comment: The way you're calling into the Activity from the Fragment is not really recommended, but it may not be the problem.  Log the values at each stage, and see exactly when they go to zeros.

Comment: I'd log them before showMap and right before creating the Marker as well

Comment: Are you trying to place a Marker in Tasmania?  What do you see visually after the code in the Activity runs?

Comment: Do you by any chance also have the default code that places a marker at (0,0)?

Comment: Do you see any Markers placed, or no Marker when the map loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming that the Markers are getting placed correctly, it looks like the only issue is getting the current view lined up correctly.

This should do it:

```
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, _long);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng).title(_title));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latlng).zoom(5).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

You might need to add these imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
```